# Google maps - a place already has a marker, how do I use this instead of lat and lng marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The place (Casa Moda Tailors) is already on Google Maps.

How do I use its marker on a Google Map instead of specifying lat and lng and having its marker very close to the Casa moda Tailors marker?

I want the large red upside-down-droplet marker to show Casa Moda Tailors and not the lat and lng marker.

Presently I have both on my Google map. I only need the Casa Moda Tailors marker and not the lat & lng marker.

I've tried Commenting out the lat and lng marker, which works. But there is no large red marker for Casa Moda Tailors, only a small dark marker.

How do I make the small dark Casa Moda Tailors marker show as a large red marker?

(I'm new to Google Maps, so I'm not sure if I'm asking my question correctly?)

Comment: I've been trying to implement this GREAT answer. But I'm getting an error: ReferenceError: google is not defined. It appears to be coming from the last line of the JavaScript: google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

Comment: OK. I just needed to put <body onload="initialize();"> All is good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hide individual POI markers.  You can hide them all, not sure if that is acceptable for your use case or not.  To hide them all, add a style to your map:

```
  styles: [{
    featureType: "poi",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [{
      visibility: "off"
    }]
  }]
```

If you want to put a marker at the location of the POI, use the [Places Service PlaceId finder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder) to get its PlaceId (or get it from the click event on the POI marker).  Then use the PlacesService `.getDetails` method to get its information, and place a marker there.

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      styles: [{
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [{
          visibility: "off"
        }]
      }]
    });
  var placeName = "Casa Moda Tailors";
  // from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder    
  // Casa Moda Tailors
  // Place ID ChIJcSqXS40PkWsR02UyBG_0DXU
  // 11/79 Queen St, Southport QLD 4215, Australia
  var placeId = "ChIJcSqXS40PkWsR02UyBG_0DXU";
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.getDetails({
    placeId: placeId
  }, function(place, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        draggable: true
      });
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent('<div jstcache="33" class="poi-info-window gm-style"> <div jstcache="2"> <div jstcache="3" class="title full-width" jsan="7.title,7.full-width">Casa Moda Tailors</div> <div class="address"> <div jstcache="4" jsinstance="0" class="address-line full-width" jsan="7.address-line,7.full-width">11/79 Queen St</div><div jstcache="4" jsinstance="1" class="address-line full-width" jsan="7.address-line,7.full-width">Southport QLD 4215</div><div jstcache="4" jsinstance="*2" class="address-line full-width" jsan="7.address-line,7.full-width">Australia</div> </div> </div> <div jstcache="5" style="display:none"></div> <div class="view-link"> <a target="_blank" jstcache="6" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=-27.972565,153.412907&amp;z=20&amp;t=m&amp;hl=en-US&amp;gl=US&amp;mapclient=apiv3&amp;cid=8434666434783765971"> <span> View on Google Maps </span> </a> </div> </div>');
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
    }
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```